# Unit Testing Brain Freeze

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit

I have a class method that looks like this:

```
private List<string> DataStoreContents = new List<string>(new[] { "", "", "", "" });

public void InputDataStore(int DataStore, string Data)
{
  DataStoreContents[DataStore - 1] = Data;
}
```

I want to make sure that DataStore is >=1 and <= 4

How can I write a unit test that ensures that?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  Title says unit testing but I don't see a unit test in the example.  Can you elaborate a little?

Comment: I want to write a unit test that makes sure I come out of the method elegantly or something if the parameter is not >= 1 and <= 4

Comment: You don't by any chance mean you want a pre-condition such as a Code contract?

Comment: I guess I could write a unit test that checks I throw an exception if that parameters aren't what I want but I don't want to throw an exception

Comment: @PhilipFourie Maybe but not entirely sure what they are?

Comment: Although I've answered below - I'm confused too. Are you saying you want to put some sort of barrier check in here to check that the DataStore value passed in is within the range 1-4, or are you saying you want an external test to check that a certain behaviour occurs when DataStore is/isn't in this range?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just write a test with a value < 1, another with a value >4 and a third test with a value within the range, then assert the expected behaviour?

Comment: I think you may be a bit confused around unit tests (or I am reading the question and comments). A unit test is something that runs seperately from you normal code execution - to test its behaviour. It sounds more like you want some sort of barrier check (a guard) to handle the situation if DataStore is out of your desired range during normal code execution. Is that correct?

Comment: @RobLevine I understand unit tests but looking at the method I now realise that if that DataStore parameter is not >=1 and <= 4 I need to fall out of the method. As the method doesn't return anything and the bhevaiour is private I cannot test it. I guess I could just make the List public and check its contents

Comment: Aside: you're needlessly creating an array just to initialize your list.  This would avoid that: `private List<string> DataStoreContents = new List<string> { "", "", "", "" };`

Comment: More on-topic: you need to define the behavior that you want if the parameter is out of range.  If not an exception, then what?  Then you can write a test for that behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either

```
Assert.IsTrue(DataStore >= 1 && DataStore <= 4);
```

or, if you prefer the fluent interface

```
Assert.That(DataStore, Is.GreaterThanOrEqualTo(1).And.LessThanOrEqualTo(4));
```

[**EDIT** - in response to you clarification above]

It sounds like you want to have some sort of barrier checking to check that the supplied values are in range.

In this case, you have a few choices:

Philip Fourie has given an answer involving code contracts.

Another simple approach is to write the barrier check yourself:

```
public void InputDataStore(int DataStore, string Data)
{
    if (DataStore < 1 || DataStore > 4)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("DataStore", "Must be in the range 1-4 inc.");
    }
    DataStoreContents[DataStore - 1] = Data;
}
```

If you don't want to throw an exception, but maybe want to log it and exit cleanly:

```
public void InputDataStore(int DataStore, string Data)
{
    if (DataStore < 1 || DataStore > 4)
    {
        // log something here and then return
        return;
    }
    DataStoreContents[DataStore - 1] = Data;
}
```

To link back to unit testing. A unit test, for example, could be a test you write to check that when `InputDataStore` is called with a value that is out of range, that it throws an expcetion. Another would be that when it is called with a value in range, it doesn't throw an exception, and it updates `DataStoreContents` correctly.

Comment: Can you expand on it as I can't see the fuller picture?

Comment: @Jon suppose the desired behavior for an out-of-range variable is to write something to the log.  Your test would pass an out-of-range variable to the method, and then check whether anything is written to the log.  A typical way of doing this would be to use a mock logger object (a mock object is typically a specialized test object that implements the same interface as the real object).  After the test is run, you would interrogate the mock logger to see whether the desired logging call was made.

Answer (score 1):

```
Assert.IsTrue(DataStore >= 1 && DataStore <= 4);
```

Comment: Can you expand on it as I can't see the fuller picture?

Comment: @Jon Utilizing the test framework, you are calling the `IsTrue()` method for your unit test.  Basically, if `DataStore >= 1 && DataStore <= 4)` isn't true, then you'll have an exception through (`Assert.IsTrue() failed`).  Otherwise, the test will pass.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a code contract with a lot of other benefits such a static code checking.
This means that you will be warned during 'code time' about using the method incorrectly.

```
public void InputDataStore(int DataStore, string Data)
{
  Contract.Requires(DataStore >= 1 && DataStore <= 4);
  DataStoreContents[DataStore - 1] = Data;
}
```

A good read here: http://devjourney.com/blog/code-contracts-part-1-introduction/

Comment: @Jon, I recommend some further reading.  I have updated my answer with a good article describing Code Contracts, they are really worth the time spent to understand them.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this?  (should all fail until you fix)

```
[Test]
[TestCase(5)]
[TestCase(0)]
[TestCase(int.MaxValue)]
[TestCase(int.MinValue)]
public void InvalidIndices(int index)
{
    Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => yourObj.InputDataStore(index, "don't care"));
}
```

or (should all pass)

```
[Test]
[TestCase(5)]
[TestCase(0)]
[TestCase(int.MaxValue)]
[TestCase(int.MinValue)]
public void InvalidIndices(int index)
{
    Assert.Throws<IndexOutOfRangeException>(() => yourObj.InputDataStore(index, "don't care"));
}
```

Comment: I would obviously need to modify the method to throw an exception in these cases

Comment: @Jon: You would need to modify the code to _not_ throw an exception (the IndexOutOfRangeException would come by default).  These are just the tests you write to define the contract with the class -- _with a bad index, do/don't throw exception_.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot really "test" here.

You can insert a check, which will be executed at runtime. Said check might help but it will not be that much more helpful than the ArrayOutOfBoundsException you'd get anyway...

Also, inserting a check is not the same thing as testing.

You should look at the Callers of the InputDataStore Function.

These you can test: Create some different situations, execute the callers and check whether they pass the right value to InputDataStore.